# Validating a "break" statement with a recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, syntax, break, formal-languages, recursive-descent

In [*Crafting Interpreters*](http://craftinginterpreters.com/), we implement a little programming language using a recursive descent parser. Among many other things, it has these statements:

```
statement → exprStmt
          | ifStmt
          | printStmt
          | whileStmt
          | block ;

block     → "{" declaration* "}" ;
whileStmt → "while" "(" expression ")" statement ;
ifStmt    → "if" "(" expression ")" statement ( "else" statement )? ;
```

One of the exercises is to [add a `break` statement](http://craftinginterpreters.com/control-flow.html#challenges) to the language. Also, it should be a syntax error to have this statement outside a loop. Naturally, it can appear inside other blocks, `if` statements etc. if those are inside a loop.

My first approach was to create a new rule, `whileBody`, to accept `break`:

```
## FIRST TRY
statement → exprStmt
          | ifStmt
          | printStmt
          | whileStmt
          | block ;

block     → "{" declaration* "}" ;
whileStmt → "while" "(" expression ")" whileBody ;
whileBody → statement
          | break ;
break     →  "break" ";" ;
ifStmt    → "if" "(" expression ")" statement ( "else" statement )? ;
```

But we have to accept `break` inside nested loops, `if` conditionals etc. What I could imagine is, I'd need a new rule for blocks and conditionals which accept `break`:

```
## SECOND TRY
statement → exprStmt
          | ifStmt
          | printStmt
          | whileStmt
          | block ;

block     → "{" declaration* "}" ;
whileStmt → "while" "(" expression ")" whileBody ;
whileBody → statement
          | break
          | whileBlock
          | whileIfStmt
whileBlock→  "{" (declaration | break)* "}" ;
whileIfStmt    → "if" "(" expression ")" whileBody ( "else" whileBody )? ;  
break     →  "break" ";"
ifStmt    → "if" "(" expression ")" statement ( "else" statement )? ;
```

It is not infeasible *for now*, but it can be cumbersome to handle it once the language grows. It is boring and error-prone to write even today!

I looked for inspiration in [C](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) and [Java](https://users-cs.au.dk/amoeller/RegAut/JavaBNF.html) BNF specifications. Apparently, none of those specifications prohibit the `break` outside loop. I guess their parsers have ad hoc code to prevent that. So, I followed suit and [added code into the parser to prevent `break` outside loops](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/jlox/commits/7697b2049be26818c6c688015ecfab3594ed191e).

### TL;DR

My questions are:

1. Would the approach of my second try even work? In other words, could a recursive descent parser handle a `break` statement that only appears inside loops?
2. Is there a more practical way to bake the `break` command inside a syntax specification?
3. Or the standard way is indeed to change a parser to prevent breaks outside loops while parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Would the approach of my second try even work? In other words, could a recursive descent parser handle a `break` statement that only appears inside loops?

Sure. But you need a lot of duplication. Since `while` is not the only loop construct, I've used a different way of describing the alternatives, which consists of adding `_B` to the name of non-terminals which might include `break` statements.

```
declaration    → varDecl
               | statement
declaration_B  → varDecl
               | statement_B
statement      → exprStmt
               | ifStmt
               | printStmt
               | whileStmt
               | block
statement_B    → exprStmt
               | printStmt
               | whileStmt
               | breakStmt
               | ifStmt_B
               | block_B
breakStmt      → "break" ";"
ifStmt         → "if" "(" expression ")" statement ( "else" statement )?
ifStmt_B       → "if" "(" expression ")" statement_B ( "else" statement_B )?
whileStmt      → "while" "(" expression ")" statement_B ;
block          → "{" declaration* "}"
block_B        → "{" declaration_B* "}"
```

Not all statement types need to be duplicated. Non-compound statement like `exprStmt` don't, because they cannot possibly include a `break` statement (or any other statement type). And the `statement` which is the target of a loop statement like `whileStmt` can always include `break`, regardless of whether the `while` was inside a loop or not.

> 2. Is there a more practical way to bake the break command inside a syntax specification?

Not unless your syntax specification has marker macros, like the specification used to describe ECMAScript.

> 3. Is there a different way to do this?

Since this is a top-down (recursive descent) parser, it's pretty straight-forward to handle this condition in the parser's execution. You just need to add an argument to every (or many) parsing functions which specifies whether a break is possible or not. Any parsing  function called by `whileStmt` would set that argument to `True` (or an enumeration indicating that break is possible), while other statement types would just pass the parameter through, and the top-level parsing function would set the argument to `False`. The `breakStmt` implementation would just return failure if it is called with `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute grammars are good at this sort of thing.  Define an inherited attribute (I'll call it LC for loop count).  The 'program' non-terminal passes LC = 0 to its children; loops pass LC = $LC + 1 to their children; all other constructs pass LC = $LC to their children.  Make the rule for 'break' syntactically valid only if $LC > 0.

There is no standard syntax for attribute grammars, or for using attribute values in guards (as I am suggesting for 'break'), but using Prolog definite-clause grammar notation your grammar might look something like the following.  I have added a few notes on DCG notation, in case it's been too long since you have used them.

```
/* nt(X) means, roughly, pass the value X as an inherited attribute. 
** In a recursive-descent system, it can be passed as a parameter.
** N.B. in definite-clause grammars, semicolon separates alternatives,
** and full stop ends a rule.  
*/

/* DCD doesn't have regular-right-part rules, so we have to  
** handle repetition via recursion.
*/ 
program -->
    statement(0);
    statement(0), program.

statement(LC) -->
    exprStmt(LC);
    ifStmt(LC);
    printStmt(LC);
    whileStmt(LC);
    block(LC);
    break(LC).

block(LC) -->
    "{", star-declaration(LC), "}".

/* The notation [] denotes the empty list, and matches zero
** tokens in the input.  
*/
star-declaration(LC) -->
    [];
    declaration(LC), star-declaration(LC).

/* On the RHS of a rule, braces { ... } contain Prolog code.  Here,  
** the code "LC2 is LC + 1" adds 1 to LC and binds LC2 to that value.
*/ 
whileStmt(LC) -->
    { LC2 is LC + 1 }, "while", "(", expression(LC2), ")", statement(LC2).

ifStmt(LC) --> "if", "(", expression(LC), ")", statement(LC), opt-else(LC).

opt-else(LC) -->
    "else", statement(LC);
    [].

/* The definition of break checks the value of the loop count:
** "LC > 0" succeeds if LC is greater than zero, and allows the
** parse to succeed.  If LC is not greater than zero, the expression
** fails.  And since there is no other rule for 'break', any attempt
** to parse a 'break' rule when LC = 0 will fail.
*/
break(LC) --> { LC > 0 }, "break", ";".
```

Nice introductions to attribute grammars can be found in Grune and Jacobs, *Parsing Techniques* and in the Springer volumes Lecture Notes in Computer Science 461 (Attribute Grammars and Their Applications*, ed. P. Deransart and M. Jourdan) and 545 (*Attribute Grammars, Applications, and Systems*, ed. H. Alblas and B. Melichar.

The technique of duplicating some productions in order to distinguish two situations (am I in a loop? or not?), as illustrated in the answer by @rici, can be regarded as  a way of pushing a Boolean attribute into the non-terminal names.